# Steam: New steam library folder must be on a filesystem mounted with execute permissions

Tags: partitioning, mount, permissions, games, steam

This question is not a duplicate, as the other questions with the same issue do not have working solutions.

I installed steam onto my main hard drive, but I need to add a library because my main hard drive doesn't have enough space for games. When I try to create a new library, I get the error message:

```
New steam library folder must be on a filesystem mounted with execute permissions.
```

The drive I'm trying to install games onto is NTFS, and gets mounted by `fstab` on `/media/reddragon/games`. However, even when adding the options `exec` and `rwx` to the options area, I still have the same error.

The current workaround is to mount the drive through `nautilus` when I log in, but It's kind of annoying, since I shutdown my computer every time I walk away for more than a few minutes.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Also, making a symbolic link to the default directory won't work, I don't like symbolic links, they're very complicated to deal with, especially when unmounting and mounting drives.